# Copy URL and Paste into Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some simple code to search movie names in IMDB search page and submit the form. How do I capture the current URL and put it into Excel.

Here is the code which I used for searching IMDB.

```
Sub IMDB_URL_Search()
    Movie = "The Shawshank Redemption"
    Range("IV1").Select
    ActiveSheet.HyperLinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        "http://www.imdb.com/find?s=all&q=" & Replace(Movie, " ", "+") _
        , TextToDisplay:="Link"
    Range("IV1").Select
    Selection.HyperLinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
End Sub
```

Thanks,
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

Excel has a built in 'Hyperlink' class to handle this.  You just need to create a hyperlink variable to store the returned hyperlink from the 'Add' function.  From there you can reference the URL you are pointing to by the 'Address' property.

```
Sub IMDB_URL_Search()

    Dim movie As String
    Dim link As Hyperlink

    movie = "The Shawshank Redemption"

    Range("IV1").Select

    Set link = ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        "http://www.imdb.com/find?s=all&q=" & Replace(movie, " ", "+") _
        , TextToDisplay:="Link")

    link.Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True

    'link.address will be the URL for this web link
    MsgBox link.Address
End Sub
```